# (Java) Can anyone explain to me why my code does not draw an oval in my GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics

I am designing a GUI that has a circle in the centre which will be filled with a different colour everytime the program is run. I have used the paint(graphics g) method to do this. When I run the following code I am just left with the blank window and no circle, can anyone explain to me why this is? I based my code off a video tutorial.

```
package weekThree;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class taskTwo {

    static Random rand = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Task Two");
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        window.setContentPane(pane);

        pane.paint(null);

        window.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        window.setSize(300,300);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        float red = rand.nextFloat();
        float green = rand.nextFloat();
        float blue = rand.nextFloat();

        Color randomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

        g.drawOval(50, 50, 25, 25);
        g.setColor(randomColor);
        g.fillOval(50, 50, 25, 25);

    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your class taskTwo is not a Swing component, and you haven't added it to the content pane of your JFrame. At a minimum you should have your class taskTwo extend JComponent, create and instance of it, and add it to the conent pane.

Comment: *Never* perform logic inside a paint method.  A paint method is called by the underlying system, often *multiple times* for a single painting operation.  Also, it may be called for every little movement of the mouse over a component.  Create your Color *outside* of your paint method, store it in an instance field, and have your paint method use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us make `class taskTwo` extend `class JPanel` and over-ride it's `paintComponent()` function. You don't need to call this function explicity. It will be called by default when a new JPanel object is created.
Make the following changes and let me know if this doesn't work out:

```
public class taskTwo extends JPanel
{ //extended JPanel so that we can over-ride the paintComponent() function in it.

//all your code for creating JFrame and adding panel to it.

//replace public void paint() with painComponent()

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
  float red=rand.nextFloat();
  float green=rand.nextFloat();
  float blue=rand.nextFloat();
   Color randomColor=new Color(red,green,blue);
   g.drawOval(50,50,25,25);
    g.setColor(randomColor);
    g.fillOval(50,50,25,25);
}
}
```

Time to clear some doubts.

What is `paintComponent()`?

- The `paintComponent()`  by default contains the design features for any swing component. `paintComponent()` is a function available for Swing Components. JPanel is a `swing component`.

Why not use `JFrame`?

- The `paintComponent()` wouldn't effect JFrame because JFrame is not a component.

Why extend JPanel?

- Simple Inheritance. Everytime you create a JPanel object, the default `paintComponent()` function in the `JPanel class` is called. The thing is you don't actually see it. When you extend JPanel, the `paintComponent()` which you have created is called instead of the default one (over-riding).

Answer (score -5):

You forgot to call your method.

```
paint();
```

Comment: Which method? **And how would you call it?**

Comment: the paint(); method, to call the method. Just write: paint();

Comment: I don't think we need to call the paint() method. It will be called by default whenever JFrame needs to be painted or framed.

Comment: @MathewsMathai Exactly. I can't believe that people are upvoting this incorrect answer.

Comment: @LarsVelthuis In case you haven't noticed, the paint method takes an argument `Graphics g`. Stop getting your friends to upvote a bad answer.

Comment: @Mike Lammers Avoid getting personal. Upvoting a wrong answer would defeat the purpose of the community.

Comment: What `Graphics` object would you pass to `paint(Graphics g)`?